# how to remove string from array

Tags: php

I´m trying to make this code works is a system to upload multiple images within a post. The images are stored at `$_SESSION['archivos']` when they are uploaded but i need to give the option to remove images from post before posting it.

The thing is that i cannot make it happen. I can not remove images from `$_SESSION['archivos']` array.

This is my code from the **remove_images_page.php:**

```
//$_POST['quitar_imagen']; EXAMPLE:    1_1467856272.jpg

$quitar_imagen = $_POST['quitar_imagen'];

$index = array_search($quitar_imagen,$_SESSION['archivos']);
if($index !== FALSE){
    unset($_SESSION['archivos'][$index]);
}
```

Comment: This isn't supposed to be tagged under jQuery

Comment: Is this your actual code? or just an example? What you have shown should work, as long as that exact value is in the array. Is it possible that the `$_POST['quitar_imagen']` value has a leading/trailing space/whitespace. As a precaution, you could do `$quitar_imagen = trim($_POST['quitar_imagen']);`